# How do I fetch data for 90 days if there is no data in 10 days using Sqplus?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I write a Query to fetch a data for 10 days from the table. If there is no data for 10 days, then i need to fetch for 50 days.But i don't know how to modify my query to fetch data for 90 days.

```
Query:

Select ep.NAME||'|'||s.id||'|'||s.SUBMISSION_DATE||'|'||E.VALUE
from SUMMARY_EXT e, summary s, enterprise ep
where e.id = id and e.name_res_key = 'Plan'
and s.id in (select id from summary where 
trunc(start_date) > trunc(sysdate) -10 and service_name ='Dplan')
```

I want to modify my query as if there is a data for 10 days then it should fetch for 10 days. If there is no data then it should fetch for 90days.

Answer (score 0):

Analytic functions can help return rows based on the existence of other rows. First, use `CASE` expressions to categorize the rows into 10 day, 50 day, or 90 day buckets. Then use analytic functions to count the number of rows in each group. Finally, select only from the relevant groups depending on those counts.

For example:

```
-- Return 10 days, 50 days, or 90 days of data.
--
--#3: Only return certain rows depending on the counts.
select id, start_date
from
(
    --#2: Count the number of rows in each category.
    select id, start_date, is_lt_10, is_lt_50, is_lt_90
        ,sum(is_lt_10) over () total_lt_10
        ,sum(is_lt_50) over () total_lt_50
        ,sum(is_lt_90) over () total_lt_90
    from
    (
        --#1: Put each row into a date category.
        select
            id, start_date,
            case when trunc(start_date) > trunc(sysdate) - 10 then 1 else 0 end is_lt_10,
            case when trunc(start_date) > trunc(sysdate) - 50 then 1 else 0 end is_lt_50,
            case when trunc(start_date) > trunc(sysdate) - 90 then 1 else 0 end is_lt_90
        from summary
        where start_date > trunc(sysdate) - 90
    )
)
where
    (is_lt_10 = 1 and total_lt_10 > 0) or
    (is_lt_50 = 1 and total_lt_10 = 0 and total_lt_50 > 0) or
    (is_lt_90 = 1 and total_lt_50 = 0 and total_lt_90 > 0);
```

The below views can help simulate date ranges. For complicated queries like this, it's helpful to start as simple as possible, and add all the other joins and columns later.

```
--Data for 10 days only.
create or replace view summary as
select 1 id, sysdate    start_date from dual union all
select 2 id, sysdate-49 start_date from dual union all
select 3 id, sysdate-89 start_date from dual union all
select 4 id, sysdate-99 start_date from dual;

--Data for 50 days only.
create or replace view summary as
select 2 id, sysdate-49 start_date from dual union all
select 3 id, sysdate-89 start_date from dual union all
select 4 id, sysdate-99 start_date from dual;

--Data for 90 days only.
create or replace view summary as
select 3 id, sysdate-89 start_date from dual union all
select 4 id, sysdate-99 start_date from dual;
```